# win32 sdk: how to make the caption/border of a child window transparent

Tags: winapi, aero, childwindow

In my win32 application I want to create a child window within the main window. I assigned these styles to the child window when calling CreateWindowEx:

```
WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION
```

The child window I get has a caption and a resizable border.
However there's no close button in the caption, and the caption/border of the child window is not transparent (I'm using the aero theme in windows 7).

Here is the screen snap:

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/f7/c6/2c/3570867/0/e68d95e88eb7.png](http://img2.pict.com/f7/c6/2c/3570867/0/e68d95e88eb7.png)

How to add close button to the caption? How can I make the caption/border transparent?

Answer (score 0):

To get the close button in the caption you will need to add the WS_SYSMENU style. As a child window your window will not have the transparency effect, you will need to use WS_POPUP for that.